# is this a bug or not?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

When we make a custom post type (in my case 'news'(slug is news also)) and a page is with name 'News' (with slug 'news').

Then when I add some pages with parent 'news', it's displaying 404 in '%postname%' permalink setting. But it's fine with default permalink structure.

I have some post types under 'news' post type also.

Slug is conflicting that's why this is happening, but I wanna know is it a bug or something else ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question - especially the title. How can this title appear in the SERPs or be found using this sites internal search?

Comment: Like kaiser said, please clarify the problem you are describing, it is somewhat unclear what you are asking. One guess would be, that there is a rewrite rules conflict between the archive page for your custom post type and the page news you created, but that's if I understood correctly what your are saying.

Comment: why negative rating to newbie all the time? May i know what i am missing in asking ? thx

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a bug. Pages are effectively a Post Type and so is your Custom Post Type. So assuming you created a Page called news but then you declared a new CPT also called news then Wordpress can't determine which is correct. 
To explain this another way, if you were to create a page called news and then another one called news, the slug would be news2 but because you are declaring the slug for the CPT this is what is causing the problem. Because you've hard-coded the slug in your functions.php file wordpress doesn't automatically amend it like it does with new pages (news2, news3, etc.).
You could consider a different slug for your CPT perhaps?
The following post may help to understand the different post types:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
HTH